# SaltStack: restart server (not only reload) on particular change

Tags: postgresql, salt-stack

In most cases it is enough to **reload** our PostgreSQL server:

```
postgresql_service:
  service.running:
    - name: postgresql
    - enable: True
    - reload: True
    - watch:
      - file: postgresql.conf
      - file: pg_hba.conf
    - require:
      - pkg: postgresql
    - failhard: True
```

But on some particular changes a reload is not enough, a restart is needed.

For example if this line gets added to postgresql.conf, a restart is required:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pglogical'
```

How can I tell Salt to use restart if the above line gets added to the config file?

Example:

1. salt runs and 'pglogical' was not in the config before and not after the salt run. The servers should get reloaded.
2. The config changes and 'pglogical' gets added. Now the server should get restarted
3. The config changes and 'pglogical' is already in the file. The server should get reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your sls architecture. for example if there is a variable in your pillar and you have a map.jinja you can handle this with something like bellow snippet.

```
{% from "postgresql/map.jinja" import pillars with context %}

postgresql_service:
  service.running:
    - name: postgresql
    - enable: True
{% if pillars.shared_preload_libraries=='pglogical' %}
    - reload: True
{% endif %}
    - watch:
      - file: postgresql.conf
      - file: pg_hba.conf
    - require:
      - pkg: postgresql
    - failhard: True
```

Comment: Does this really work. I want it like this: if pglogical gets added, then a restart is needed. If it was added in a previous salt run, then reload should be done. Does your "if" detect the change?

Comment: if you set pglogical in your pillars. every time salt runs it restarts the service.

Comment: I updated the question to be more precise. Please tell me, if the question is not clear enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, using a specific pillar to trigger a full restart instead of a reload can only be used if you specify this pillar once and not at every run.

One option could be to specify this pillar on the command-line, something like this `salt 'minion' state.sls postgres pillar="{'restart': true}"` can be used. Then in your state you verify the presence of this pillar.

Other options are possible (like running your main state+the state for restart when you need it) but all I think about need the salt user to know when asking for a restart.